# Display Real-time processed images in Raspberry Pi

Tags: image, real-time

I am working on real time image processing in raspberry Pi.
Goal is to fetch and process 64x64 frame with 60 fps.
I am using numpy to process these frames.
And i want to display these processed images continuously in real time.
I tried searching how to do it but could not find sufficient help.
I found how to display an array as an image but it opens image viewer which pauses everything.
I want to see these processed images one by one like a video is being played.

Thanks in advance

Comment: opencv has ways to display the video as its being processed, 60fps seems a little fast if you are doing any sort of processing.